# bashrc function that will execute the output result

Tags: bash

I'm trying to search on my history grab the last history item and execute my finding. Here is my current function on my .bashrc

```
function hgl() {
        history | grep  "$1" | grep -v hg | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print "!"$1 }'
}
```

This function will print an output like this `!2345`, but I want to be able to run that output and for I get the last command of my history search.

Comment: You want to “eval” the result to run it as a command. I am not sure that works with history though.

Comment: If you can’t use the eval command on history statements, you could try grep’ing the .history file for the command and  eval’ing the command you get back.

Comment: Note that history expansion already provides a way to search for a fixed string in your command history: `!?foo?` will execute the most recent command containing "foo".

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it works:

```
function hgl() {
        RESULT=`history | grep  "$1" | grep -v hg | tail -n 1 | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`
        eval $RESULT
}
```

Comment: You should double-quote `$RESULT`, or you can get really weird problems under obscure circumstances. To see this, run `echo "2 * 3"`, and then re-run it with this function.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the number of the command, you can use `fc` to run it:

```
$ help fc
fc: fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] or fc -s [pat=rep] [command]
    Display or execute commands from the history list.

    fc is used to list or edit and re-execute commands from the history list.
    FIRST and LAST can be numbers specifying the range, or FIRST can be a
    string, which means the most recent command beginning with that
    string.

    Options:
      -e ENAME  select which editor to use.  Default is FCEDIT, then EDITOR,
            then vi
```

If you don't want to edit it first, you can use a do-nothing command, like `:`.

So something like:

```
hgl() {
    local RESULT=$(history | grep  "$1" | grep -v hg | awk 'END { print $1 }')
    [[ -n $RESULT ]] && fc -e : "$RESULT"
}
```